# Squares as rating bars

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some help trying to create squares for a rating bars but I'm a little confused on where to start. I added a image of what I want them to look like

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? try to think HTMLish... for instance one div wraps the whole component, then (according to the number of stripes) append sub-elements with appropriate margins. that's just one example.

Comment: So what your saying is create a wrapper then followed by 10 other divs? My first thought was trying to use tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.Square {
    width: .5%;
    border: 2px solid #00316A;
    float:left;
    height: 30px;
}

.MarginRight {
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.Fill {
    background-color: #00316A;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight Fill"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight"></div>
      <div class="Square MarginRight"></div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice work. looks like exactly what you needed.